# How do I show results that start with a letter e.g A only

Tags: c++

I have a `list.txt` file.

It contains about 100 records, but if user `cin` a letter, e.g A, I just want show all records containing A in the loop.

Records are recorded in line break format, in shell command we use A*, but in C++, how do we do it?

Example:

```
Alfred
Alpha
Augustine
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
```

Comment: The data in your example is sorted; will this always be the case?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bunch of ways to do it, chose the one you like more ;)

---

Crappy solution with strings and streams:

```
std::vector< std::string > vec;//this will hod the file data
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");//the input file stream
std::string tmp;//a temporary string

while( ifs >> tmp )//reading the whole data from the file
    vec.push_back(tmp);

for( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )
    if(vec[i][0] == 'a')//vec[i][0] stands for "the first symbol of element number i in vector"
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;//outputting the string if it starts with 'a'
```

If you have c++11, you can replace the `for` with this range-based for:

```
for( std::string & s : vec )
    if(s.at(0) == 'a')
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Or, you can complicate things further and replace the `for` with `std::copy_if` and lambdas from c++11 (IMO it's much too complicated and hard to read for such a simple occasion, but still I'll include it):

```
//this will copy all strings starting with 'a' into res vector.
std::vector< std::string > res;
std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), back_inserter(res), [](const std::string & s){ return s[0]=='a'; } );
```

---

If you don't need to store the strings anywhere, it's easier:

```
std::vector< std::string > vec;
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
std::string tmp;

while( ifs >> tmp )
    if( tmp.at(0) == 'a' )
        std::cout << tmp;
```

---

A more old-school solution without using streams of strings:

```
FILE * f = fopen("test.txt", "r");//opening the file
if( !f )//checking in case it didn't open
    return -1;

char buffer[255];//buffer for the strings being read from file
while( !feof(f) )
{
    fgets(buffer, 255, f);//getting a string
    if(buffer[0] == 'a')//printing if it starts with 'a'
        printf("%s", buffer);
}
fclose(f);//don't forget to close the file
```

Comment: You really do mention a bit of everything.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a decently elegant, possibly more idiomatic solution:

```
#include <algorithm> //for copy_if
#include <cctype> //for tolower
#include <fstream> //for ifstream
#include <iostream> //for cout, cin
#include <iterator> //for istream_iterator, ostream_iterator
#include <string> //for string

int main() {
    char letter;
    std::cout << "Enter the letter to look for: ";
    std::cin >> letter; //I didn't validate it

    std::ifstream fin ("names.txt");

    std::istream_iterator<std::string> ifbegin (fin); //begin file iter
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> ifend; //end file iter
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> obegin (std::cout, " "); //begin out iter

    std::copy_if (ifbegin, ifend, obegin, //copy from file to output if
        [letter] (const std::string &str) { //capture letter
            return std::tolower (str [0]) == std::tolower (letter);
        } //copy if starts with upper/lower case of entered letter
    );
}
```

Note that it does require C++11 for `copy_if` and the lambda. This outputs every name in the file starting with the upper/lower case of the letter entered, separated by spaces. It performs the same when the data is sorted as it does when the data is unsorted.

As Luc points out below, though, this will read separate names for lines with spaces. If you want to get around that, you need a custom replacement for which `operator>>` reads a line.

Step 1: Create the replacement:

```
struct Line {
    std::string text; //note I made this public to save time
    operator std::string() const {return text;} //less work later
};
```

Step 2: Modify `operator>>` to read a line for the struct:

```
std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, Line &line) {
    std::getline (in, line.text); //get whole line
    return in;
}
```

Step 3: Change the iterators to use our custom struct. Note that the last stays a string because it's implicitly convertible to one. Let's also separate the printing by newlines so we can tell that it was a line, not a word:

```
std::istream_iterator<Line> ifbegin (fin); //begin file iter
std::istream_iterator<Line> ifend; //end file iter
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> obegin (std::cout, "\n"); //begin out iter
```

Step 4: Change the lambda to suit our needs:

```
[letter] (const std::string &line) {
        return !line.empty() //we introduced the possibility of "" 
               && (std::tolower (line [0]) == std::tolower (letter));
}
```

4 easy steps later, we're done!

Comment: What if a line contains spaces? Your solution would read the words separately, while the question states that records are delimited by line breaks. You could solve this by reading `Line`s instead of `std::string`s, `Line` being a custom struct with an extraction operator that does a `getline` on the input stream.

Comment: @LucTouraille, Yes, I was counting on the records being as shown in the post. If there were spaces allowed, I thought the OP would put them into one line at least. I can add that, though

Comment: @LucTouraille, There, added and tested the steps for turning it into a line reader. Doesn't boost have an istream iterator that reads whole lines or something, though?

Comment: I never saw anything like that in any Boost library, but I may have missed it. On a side note, you could simplify the use of the `Line` class by making it convertible to `std::string`. This way, you would not need to define an insertion operator, nor to modify the lambda, and you would be able to use the `istream_iterator<Line>` "trick" with all functions operating on `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either remove_copy_if if you actually need the new list or for_each using a lambda expression that checks the predicate if you don't. Can you elaborate a bit what you mean by "show"?

Comment: I am trying to read from this text file, and at the while loop, i will printf out the record, if the word first letter start with "A" , it will printf, else it won't printf

Comment: Oh, so you just want to know how to check what the first letter is?

Comment: @Baokychen: If you already wrote some code, you should probably include it in your question, to give SO users more information about where you have trouble.